# visual studio 6 "find all references"?

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-6

in visual studio 6 is there a way to "Find All References".  Don't see a shortcut key [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: AFAIK, `Find All References` is part of refactoring, and refactoring didn't exist in VS 6. My memory could be wrong, though; that was a long time ago. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "Find All References" in VB6. There is however an add-in that can find all references to procedures and functions (not variables). The add-in is called MZ-tools and the option you're looking for is called "Procedure Callers".

You can download the add-in over [here](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) (<del>freeware</del> trial version).

You can download the old freeware version 3 from [this dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgalegvb8259fyq/mztools3vb6setup.exe?dl=0) of mine. Don't be fooled by the version nummer, that is the latest vb6 version available.

Comment: +1 VB6 just **isn't installed** until you have installed MZ Tools!

Comment: @Martin looks promising.  thanks for the link... and to believe i used to one of those VB defenders :)

Comment: Except, of course, that it's no longer freeware as of now but has an USD 79.99 price tag - just saying.